# How to make my Django code DRY and efficient using comprehensive lists?

Tags: django, django-models

In the following code, I can see 2 distincts problems:

1. This is not DRY, because the whole logic in `date__range` is the same for both lists (A and B). How would you solve this? I tried with methods as parameters without success, not sure to understand how to implement this.
2. The get_x_events() is called in each loop round, I guess this is NOT efficient..

class Event(models.Model):

```
    @classmethod
    def get_stats(cls, owner, nb_days, offset):

        # Building a list with comprehensive list calling the get_A_events() classmethod of the EventA class
        list_A = [EventA.get_A_events(owner).filter(
            date__range=(
                now_day - timedelta(days=offset) - timedelta(days=d),
                now_day - timedelta(days=offset) - timedelta(days=d-1))).count() \
            for d in range(nb_days)]

        # Doing the same with another method of another class
        # The logic is exactly the same thought...
        list_B = [EventB.get_B_events(owner).filter(
            date__range=(
                now_day - timedelta(days=offset) - timedelta(days=d),
                now_day - timedelta(days=offset) - timedelta(days=d-1))).count() \
            for d in range(nb_days)]

        return zip(list_A, list_B)
```

My models are organised this way:

- class Event(models.Model)
- class EventA(Event)
- class EventB(Event)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_events_list(event_object_with_owner, offset, nb_days):
    event_list = [ 
                   event_object_with_owner.filter(
                   date__range=(
                   now_day - timedelta(days=offset) - timedelta(days=d),
                   now_day - timedelta(days=offset) - timedelta(days=d-1))).count() \
                   for d in range(nb_days)
                  ]
    return event_list


event_list_A = get_events_list(EventA.get_A_events(owner), offset, nb_days)

event_list_B = get_events_list(EventB.get_B_events(owner), offset, nb_days)
```

Comment: It works thanks! Small mistakes: the method to call is get_events_list (not get_events), and `d` doesn't need to be passed as a parameter since it's only used in the loop for comprehensive list. (I edited your answer)

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good start.

```
kwargs = {
    'date__range': (now_day - timedelta(days=offset) - timedelta(days=d),
                    now_day - timedelta(days=offset) - timedelta(days=d-1)),
}

list_A = [
    EventA.get_A_events(owner).filter(**kwargs).count()
    for d in range(nb_days)
]

list_B = [
    EventB.get_B_events(owner).filter(**kwargs).count()
    for d in range(nb_days)
]
```

Beyond this you should probably refactor your models. Having `EventA` and `EventB` as opposed to a single `Event` model suggests you're violating the DRY principle further down. The same applies to the `get_A_events` and `get_B_events` methods, why not a single `get_events` method?

Comment: Note that `d` is a local variable in the list comprehension, it cannot be used outside of that scope.

Comment: Thanks for help. Your solution does not raise any error but gives me an empty queryset (instead of 3 items). As @knbk said, I have a warning because of `d`variable :) And to answer your question, I actually have an Event class, EventA and EventB are [inherited classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

Comment: Ah, in that case it's worth having a look at [this](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager).

Comment: 2 things: 1) I needed this tool so much for another stuff in my code so thank you! However, what about compatibility with future Django version?  2) In this particular question, I do want to split A and B events to display 2 lines in my chart. Is the 'special' manager will help in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Your query can certainly be optimized. Right now, you execute a sql query for each iteration in your list comprehension. Using annotation, you can reduce this to 2 queries:

```
from django.db.models import Count

list_A = [a['num_days'] for a in EventA.get_A_events(owner).filter(date__range=(
             now_day - timedelta(days=offset),
             now_day - timedelta(days=offset+nb_days))) \
             .values('date').annotate(num_days=Count('id'))]
```

You can use `**kwargs` for the filter call, as Matt suggested, but to what extend you can adhere to the DRY principle mostly depends on the logical structure of your models, mostly their inheritance chain. If you can post your models I might be able to help you further.

Comment: Thx! I added my model organization, based on model inheritance.